# How can I run google death tests in debug only?

Tags: c++, googletest

We have a series of death tests that check that specific debug `asserts` fire. For example, we construct something like this:

```
LockManager::LockManager(size_t numManagedLocks) :
    _numManagedLocks(numManagedLocks)
{
    assert(_numManagedLocks <= MAX_MANAGABLE_LOCKS &&
        "Attempting to manage more than the max possible locks.");
```

And we have a test for its failure:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(LockManager sutLockManager(constants::MAX_NUMBER_LOCKS + 1), 
    "Attempting to manage more than the max possible locks.");
```

Since assert is only compiled in debug, these tests will fail when the component is built in release. Is the best way to avoid this to wrap `EXPECT_DEATH` tests in a `DEBUG` detection macro:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
     // DEATH TESTS
#endif
```

Or is there an approach that is better and specific to Google Test?

Comment: You could just exclude these tests using the [`--gtest_filter`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#running-a-subset-of-the-tests) command line argument.

Comment: @Thomas, true but it is a pain, because then you have to disable a series of tests from different test cases. We could add it to our running script, but i feel like a better solution would be a special expanded macro or something.

Comment: You could use a naming convention, like ending all these tests with the word `Death`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that GTest have a solution to this now:
[EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH)

Answer (score 1):

Since assert() macro uses preprocessor logic, the solution should be also on this level - via conditional compilation.
You can use GoogleTest specific DISABLED_ syntax (See [Temporarily Disabling Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md)) and write something like

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_TEST_ 
#else
#define DEBUG_TEST_ DISABLED_
#endif
```

Your original suggestion also looks good, however I would better write direct condition:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We generated a working MACRO to use in place of full death tests or just the `ASSERT_DEATH` that appears in amongst other tests:

```
#if defined _DEBUG

    #define DEBUG_ONLY_TEST_F(test_fixture, test_name) \
        TEST_F(test_fixture, test_name)
    #define DEBUG_ONLY_ASSERT_DEATH(statement, regex) \
        ASSERT_DEATH(statement, regex)

#else

    #define DEBUG_ONLY_TEST_F(test_fixture, test_name) \
        TEST_F(test_fixture, DISABLED_ ## test_name)
    #define DEBUG_ONLY_ASSERT_DEATH(statement, regex) \
        std::cout << "WARNING: " << #statement << " test in " << __FUNCTION__ << " disabled becuase it uses assert and fails in release.\n";

#endif
```

Of course we will need to override any other test types we use (eg. `TEST_P` or `EXPECT_DEATH`), but this shouldn't be a big problem.